# Pandas omits first row while plotting

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, plot

I have this code, which is supposed to count number of values based on datetime, months in this example.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Nov 28 13:31:33 2016

@author: ...
"""
import sys  
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

"""read and count"""
df = pd.read_csv('meteo_merged.csv', parse_dates=[1])
df['datetime'] = df.datetime.apply(lambda x: x.month)

x = df.groupby(['datetime']).count()
df2 = pd.read_csv('policja.csv', parse_dates=[1])
df2['datetime'] = df2.datetime.apply(lambda x: x.month)
p = df2.groupby('datetime').count()

"""plot"""
ax = x.plot(y='station', kind='bar', legend=False)
ax2 = p.plot(ax=ax, color='g', secondary_y=True, legend=False, rot=60, figsize=(8,6))
ax2.lines[0].set_linewidth(3)

"""axes labels etc."""
godziny = ['styczeń', 'luty', 'marzec', 'kwiecień', 'maj', 'czerwiec', 'lipiec', 'sierpień', 'wrzesień', 'październik', 'listopad', 'grudzień']
ax.set_xticklabels(godziny)
ax.set_ylabel('Liczba dni z ograniczoną widocznością dla danego miesiąca').set_color('blue')
ax2.set_ylabel('Liczba zdarzeń drogowych w danym miesiącu').set_color('green')
ax.set_xlabel('Miesi\xc4\x84c')

"""ticks settings"""
ax.spines['left'].set_color('blue')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('green')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='blue')
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', colors='green')

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.savefig('mgla_miesiace.svg', format='svg', dpi=300)
```

X axis starts from second month, though DataFrame has 12 rows:

```
       station  humidity
datetime                   
1           15101     15101
2           11171     11171
3           12057     12057
4           13031     13031
5           19835     19835
6           17421     17421
7           18145     18145
8           17980     17980
9           21347     21347
10          22050     22050
11          22265     22265
12          11279     1127>> >9
```

[Plot result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDrUf.png)

I have a very similar code, that does the same, only for hours and it works fine, every row is plotted. The only difference is line:

```
df['datetime'] = df.datetime.apply(lambda x: x.hour)
```

I have no idea what seems to be the problem here. Also, there seems to be a problem with coding. no matter what I try, I can't plot letters such as ą, ę, ó, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For your font problem, it can be fixed by forcing matplotlib to use another font. For example, if you're using Ubuntu you could try Liberation Serif

```
matplotlib.rc('font', family='Liberation Serif')
```

Of course you can change that depending which font you want as long as it supports the characters you want in the plot.

For the month problem, have you tried expanding the axis with plt.axis?

Comment: Questions should be asked in comments instead

Comment: adding plt.xlim([0,12]) made it show 12 bars, but plot is displaced. Values from both dataframes don't correspond to one another. Plotting only the original bar plot without secondary y gives expected results, no data is missing.